# Determining Genie Style AoE damage

Tags: pathfinder-1e, fighting-style

> [Shaitan Earthblast (Combat)](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/shaitan-earthblast-combat/)
>
> Benefit: While using the Shaitan Style feat, as a standard action, you can spend two Elemental Fist attempts to unleash a 20-foot column of acid that has a 5-foot radius and erupts from a point of origin within 30 feet of you. Creatures caught in the column take **your unarmed strike damage** plus the acid damage from your Elemental Fist and are staggered for 1 round. A successful Reflex save (DC 10 + 1/2 your character level + your Wis modifier) reduces the damage by half and prevents a target from being staggered

I'd like some clarification on what does and doesn't affect "unarmed strike damage":

- Bonuses from class skills? (such as a [Fighter's Weapon Training](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Fighter/#TOC-Weapon-Training-Ex-))
- Enhancement bonus from magic items? (such as a +2 Amulet of Mighty Fists)
- Special abilities from magic items? (such as a Shock Amulet of Mighty Fists)
- Damage or other effects from feats? (Weapon Specialization, Power
  Attack, Bleeding Attack, etc.)

Obviously this question extends to all the [Genie](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/efreeti-touch-combat/) [Style](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/marid-coldsnap-combat/) [AoE attacks](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/djinni-spin-combat/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your Unarmed Strike Damage includes bonuses but non on-hit effects

What does this mean? If something increases the damage your attack does, it applies. If something happens when you land the attack, it does not.

- Bonuses from class skills? (such as a Fighter's Weapon Training) **Yes**

  - Bonuses, by definition, add to the related number

  > Bonus: Bonuses are numerical values that are added to checks and statistical scores. Most bonuses have a type, and as a general rule, bonuses of the same type are not cumulative (do not “stack”)—only the greater bonus granted applies.
- Enhancement bonus from magic items? (such as a +2 Amulet of Mighty Fists) **Yes**

  - As above, Enhancement is a type of bonus
- Damage or other effects from feats? (Weapon Specialization, Power Attack, Bleeding Attack, etc.) **Some**

  - If it adds a bonus, even untyped (such as [Weapon Specialization](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/weapon-specialization-combat/)), then it works.
  - [Power Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat/) *would* work except you are unable to activate the Feat "You must choose to use this feat before making an attack roll, and its effects last until your next turn."*
  - [Bleeding Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/belier-s-bite-combat/) would not, because it is an effect that you get if you land the attack, not a bonus to the attack.
- Special abilities from magic items? (such as a Shock Amulet of Mighty Fists) **No**

  - Abilities that work "when you hit" something are not a bonus and do not count toward the damage of the attack. A good rule of thumb is that anything not multiplied on a crit would not be the attack damage.

---

*I am not positive that this is how Power Attack is supposed to be limited, but it is how I rule that line from the Feat. If your GM allows you to activate Power Attack without declaring an attack, then it *would* work.